# Sporadic black screen/freeze around boot time booting into Windows helps, Precision M6700, i5 processor, AMD graphics, 18.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04, dell, amd-graphics

The black screen may occur before, during or after boot.  I have discovered that if I force off, power down with on off button, I can work around it.  Sometimes it takes 2 or 3 boots before I am in.  After that the install is very stable.

I have also discovered that if I boot to Windows 7, for a just a moment, and then turn that off and boot to 18.04 everything is stable and works perfectly. I have read several threads about this and they all seem to think it is a graphics issue, but the suggestions don’t address my issue which is intermittent. Why would my graphics driver be bad and then be good? I'm not a programmer but I don't understand this, or why Windows could fix it somehow.

No additional drivers available from Software & Updates.

- Ubuntu 18.04
- Memory: 7.7 GiB
- Processor: Intel Core i5-3320M CPU @ 2.60GHz × 4
- Graphics: AMD Cape Verde
- GNOME: 3.28.2
- OS type: 64-bit
- Disk: 301.6 GB

There are two separate hard drives in this computer.  One has Windows 7 on it all by itself.  The other has Ubuntu 18.04 on it all by itself.  BIOS boots Ubuntu first or from GRUB I can force it to boot Windows.  Windows is very stable but I prefer to use Ubuntu.

I am a long time Ubuntu user but I am not a programmer. I was able to glean the following from my terminal using commands I read on the web.

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Heathrow XT [Radeon HD 7870M]
```

---

```
$ find /dev -group video
/dev/fb0
/dev/dri/card0
/dev/dri/renderD128
```

---

```
$ glxinfo | grep -i vendor
server glx vendor string: SGI
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
Vendor: X.Org (0x1002)
OpenGL vendor string: X.Org
```

Comment: I had a similar issue with an AMD 7970 TAHITI graphics card (Boot to black screen, suspend, wake it up always worked though). I upgraded the BIOS to the latest available release and it fixed the issue.

Comment: Seems a bit of a shot in the dark... On what device did you have this problem? What BIOS version?

Comment: I agree, but it was the only solution that worked in my case. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1796574